# is correct for finding the work needed to stretch a spring?

Tags: calculus

Q: Suppose the work W_0 done when a spring is stretched 6 inches from its natural length is 1/2 ft-lb. Find the work W done in extending the spring 3 more inches.

How I solved:

W = ∫[a to b] [kx] dx

work was given as 1/2 ft-lbs:

1/2 = ∫[0 to 6] [kx]dx

1/2 = (x^2 / 2) *k | [0 to 6]

1/2 = (6^2/2)*k

k = 9

therefore, 
W = ∫[6 to 9] 9x dx

W = 9x^2 / 2 | [6 to 9]

= 9(9)^2 / 2 - 9(6)^2 / 2

Am I wrong? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Your k is wrong. Yet you could have simply used:
$$Work=\Delta PE$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}.k(x_2^2-x_1^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}.k(9^2-6^2)$$

For $k$, $$W_o=\frac{1}{2}k6^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of $k$ is wrong.  The idea for $W$ is right.

Comment: Thank you, would the total work be 810?

Comment: You also have a unit problem.  The work is in foot pounds, so the distances should be in feet.  The integral to determine $k$ should be from $0$ to $1/2$  That cancesl out at the end, just leaving $k$ with units different from lb/foot.  With your units $k=1/36$ so the integral is lower.

Comment: Thank you, at the end wouldn't it be W = 18k? Because 6^2/1 = 18? I must be missing something here.

Comment: Right, I remember reading about the conversion between ft-lb to feet, this part kind of confuses me. Because it's originally in inches but the work is in foot-lbs, how is this converted over to have correct limits of integration?

Comment: It is just $6$ inches is $1/2$ foot.  Your equation for $k$ is $\frac 12=\frac {36}2k$, so $k=1/36$

Comment: Oh lord, I mixed up basic rules. Thank you! I see what I did wrong.